# VIM replaces backspace with ^?

Tags: vim, gnome, xterm, stty

Whenever I type backspace in VIM the editor inserts `^?`.
I've edited `.vimrc` to have `set backspace=indent,eol,start` and it didn't work. `set backspace=2` Didn't work either.

I've read that you need to edit the XTerm file inside /etc/X11/... but the folder and the file do not exist.

This is not a duplicate because I've tried previously suggested solutions and it didn't work.

Comment: Create the folder and file?

Answer (score 1):

Editing `/etc/X11/app-defaults/XTerm` would be a possibility, but if you do not have the file perhaps you are using a different terminal.

The problem is not the setting you are using in `vim`, but that the terminal description and the terminal do not agree on what "backspace" sends.

Usually "backspace" is the same as the `stty erase` value, which you can see using `stty -a`, e.g.,

```
~ (101) stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 40; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^H; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

If `stty` shows `^H` and the terminal actually sends `^?` (ASCII DEL, or 127), then `vim` is likely to get confused.

In vim's help-file, it claims that if you put

```
:fixdel
```

in your `.vimrc`, it is able to *Do The Right Thing*:

```
:fix[del]               Set the value of 't_kD':
                                't_kb' is     't_kD' becomes    ~
                                  CTRL-?        CTRL-H
                                not CTRL-?      CTRL-?

                        (CTRL-? is 0177 octal, 0x7f hex) {not in Vi}

                        If your delete key terminal code is wrong, but the
                        code for backspace is alright, you can put this in
                        your .vimrc:                  
                                :fixdel
                        This works no matter what the actual code for
                        backspace is.
```

Comment: But when I do it, backspace deletes the NEXT character, not the previous.

Comment: Perhaps if you added the output of `stty -a` and `echo $TERM` to your question (as well as identifying which terminal program you are using), that would provide enough information.